# iPad scrolls back to top after clicking on a dropdown in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, safari

I'm running into a iPad bug on our new SEOshop theme and I just can't figure out what it is.

In the theme we've created a "shop now" functionality. The "shop now" button shows a pop-up with extra product specifications. In the pop-up there is a dropdown with some extra product options. If I click on the dropdown, (on iPad) the browser scrolls back to top. I think it has something to do with the default dropdown action, but I can't debug it.

Is there a way to prevent this default action, where it doesn't scroll to top?

[amaseo.webshopapp.com/en/women/accessories/](http://amaseo.webshopapp.com/en/women/accessories/)

The problem only shows on a iPad Air, iOS 8.3, Safari. It works fine in Chrome.

Comment: the .preventDefault() prototype prevents the standard behaviour of an event, hence you should try to prevent it in such a way, but I suspect the problem may also be elsewhere. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault